# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-mllib

...

```
val cols: Seq[String] = Seq("item", "SR", "RP")
 val vecToSeq = udf((v:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector) => v.toArray)
val exprs = cols.zipWithIndex.map{ case(c,i) => $"_tmp".getItem(i).alias(c)}
val DoubleDF = result5.select(vecToSeq($"vectorCol").alias("_tmp")).select(exprs:_*)
```

...(Sorry. I've included all the code that I think is relevant because I do not know how much information I should give.)

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{Rating,ALS}
...

val als = new org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS().setRank(10).setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.01).setUserCol("user").setItemCol("item").setRatingCol("rating")
...

val itemFactors = model.itemFactors
val item = Popular.select($"item").map(line => line.getDouble(0)).take(10).map(_.toInt)

val popularFactored = itemFactors.where(item.map($"id" === _).reduce(_||_)) 

val exprs2 = (0 until 10).map(i => $"_tmp2".getItem(i).alias(s"z$i"))
val factored = popularFactored.select(($"features").alias("_tmp2")).select(exprs2:_*)

val AF = (0 until 10).map(i => factored.agg(avg(s"z$i")).first.getDouble(0)).toArray


val toFloat = udf((line: Seq[Float]) => line.map(_.toDouble))
val test = itemFactors.withColumn("testX",toFloat(itemFactors("features")))
val itemFactors2 = test.select($"id",$"testX")


val itemFeatures2 = itemFactors2.map{line => val feature = line.getAs[Seq[Double]]("testX")
val item = line.getAs[Int]("id")
(item,feature.toArray)}

val itemFeaturesR = itemFeatures2.rdd


val ItemFS= itemFeaturesR.map { case (id,factor) =>
val arr= new DoubleMatrix(10)
for (i <- 0 until 10){
val itemVector = new DoubleMatrix(AF)
val factorVector = factor(i)
arr.put(i,factorVector)
val sims = cosineSimilarity(arr.getRow(i), itemVector)
(id,sims)
}
}
```

I am now measuring the cosine similarity. However, when I run the above code, I get an error **'org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable**

```
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2056)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:366)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:365)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:365)
  ... 59 elided
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: _tmp[0] AS `item`)
        - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
        - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@76a47056)
        - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)


- object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(_tmp[0] AS `item`, _tmp[1] AS `SR`, _tmp[2] AS``RP 
   '
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add more of the code? There might be several issues.

Comment: @AndreiT. Code was updated. Please confirm it once.

Comment: Try marking the `exprs` variable with `@transient`.

Comment: @AndreiT. Sorry. I am a beginner and I did not understand exactly. How do you specifically change it?

Comment: On the third line (of the first example), just type `@transient val exprs = ...` instead of just `val exprs = ...`

Comment: @AndreiT. Thank you for answer. But I did what you said, but I still get errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try put on class definition `with Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

**'org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable'** is quit obvious that your class is not able to be serialized. Since Spark is parallel computing and it needs to share code (closure) across the cluster. For that it needs you to serialize your code. Extend your class definition with *Serializable*.

Comment: Sorry. I am a beginner and I did not understand exactly. How do you specifically change it?